# Is there any drawback to have lots of installed and enabled extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every extension added to VS Code is enabled by default. This makes me wonder : does having dozens of them as any impact on the editor performance ?

In practice, a given project usually uses only a few of the installed extensions. For example, a C# project doesn't need all the other languages linter and specific tools.

So, **how does VS Code manage extensions ?** Does it enable them on-the-fly, as needed ?
It doesn't seem to me that it takes more time to load as I add more extensions over time.

I couldn't find any information on the subject in the [VS Code Extension documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery). Extensions can be disabled individually within a workspace, but that's it.

Comment: @the person who voted to close because the question is "too broad": I would like some suggestion to improve it. I thought about changing the title to "How does VS Code manage extensions" as it would encompass all the sub-questions. Other idea ?

Comment: You can start `code`  with an `--extensions-dir` argument. I do this an seperate a code instance with ColdFusion specific plugins from the one with PHP specific plugins. I firstly fear it's a matter of performance and secondly it simply annoys me when extensions that I don't need currently pop up with notifications. I therefore try to keep the number of running extensions small.